# How to catch JSON object in controller Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a login api in which i send input value as an JSON object,but the problem is that it doesn't capture any input data.
My controller function is something like this

```
public function login(Request $request){

    //I tried to check if i am receiving input here or not         
    if($request->input('provider')=='web'){
        //Do something
    }else{
        //Return error message
    }
}
```

But the problem is it seems like i cant retrive the JSON Input values

I am testing this with `postman` with the following parameter in header

```
Content-Type: application/json,
Accept:application/json
```

I followed the Laravel documentation  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests
and tried to check with `$data= $request->input('provider');` if i am getting any response or not but i still the same no response.

I also tried with the following

```
$data= $request->json()->all(); ///Getting Null
$data= json_decode($request->getContent()); ///Getting Null
```

I found an article which is similer problem as this on laracast 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-validate-json-input-using-requests But those solution also didnt work for me. Maybe because those are outdate.

So can anyone please help me out how can i retrive JSON input data in the controller to do further actions ?

Comment: Please show results of `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Are you sending a GET or POST request?

Comment: are you sure that the request in postman succeeds?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `dd($request->all()); `doesn't show anything .

@patriziotomato i am sending `POST` request

@Wreigh yes,becz if i turn off `Content-Type : application/json` i do get response as expected to, only when i send JSON object i do not get any response, I tried to call the api from my anguler application too same thing

Comment: What does the form/javascript code look like that's posting the JSON?

Comment: Postman API testing , with header content type as application/json , and in body the post values